# Give permission if it is staff. django

Tags: python, html, django

I have this code in django and I want the button to appear if the user is a super user or staff. I don't know how I should put it, I tried with is_superuser or is_staff but it didn't work.

`{% if request.user == post.user %} <div class="trash"> <a href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:#657786; font-size: 20px" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div> {% endif %}`

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zizx0.png)

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser == True or request.user.is_staff == True %} <div class="trash"> <a href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:#657786; font-size: 20px" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div> {% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, I already solved it thank you very much, I had missed the user.is_superuser, I was just putting is_superuser haha

Answer (score -1):

People already solved it, I just put an 'or user.is_superuser'